# Unable to call my WebApi method from AngularJs

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have created a webapi

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Movie")]
    public class MovieController : ApiController
    {
        //IMovieRepository repo;
        //public MovieController(IMovieRepository _repo)
        //{
        //    this.repo = _repo;
        //}


        [Route("latest")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                //var getAllMovies = repo.GetAll();
                return Ok("hello");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Ok(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

My angularJs Code

```
var _getMovies = function () {

        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/movie/latest').then(function (results) {
            return results;
        });
    };
```

When I try to execute this directly from url
it gives me exception like this.
[image]

Comment: You are hitting your API, that error is not coming from Angular. Set a breakpoint in every controller action to see what route you are actually hitting.

Comment: I have set break point every where, but it was not hitting any break point

Comment: Somewhere your api is throwing an exception and it is dutifully serializing it and sending it back to the client. Do you have `return OK(ex)` anywhere? Do a network profile with the browser F12 tools and examine the requests and response codes.

Comment: It could be that you are running an old version of the code, did you rebuild your project? repo.GetAll() is likely throwing null reference from old code. Make sure you are running in debug mode with pdb files enabled

Comment: @Titanium: I have commented that line of code. I'm simply returning Hello inside `Ok`

Comment: @AmitKumar - The exception is coming from `Line 31` inside a `Lambda expression`. If you have commented it, then try rebuilding the application and execute the request again.

Comment: Just try web browser  or fiddler to ping your api request..And then try code .because you need to find its error caught in angular or wep api side..after that you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you get an exception, *the call to your api is actually working* because the server is throwing an exception. The exception is coming from the serverside code, AngularJS is not related at all with the issue.

The exception you got probably occured with code like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Movie")]
public class MovieController : ApiController
{
    IMovieRepository repo;

    [Route("latest")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            //var getAllMovies = repo.GetAll();
            return Ok("hello");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The null reference was your repo not being instanciated.

With what you showed us in your question being like:

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/Movie")]
    public class MovieController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("latest")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                //var getAllMovies = repo.GetAll();
                return Ok("hello");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Ok(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

There is no reason you hit that kind of exception, so I'd say, clean, build and try again !

With something like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Movie")]
public class MovieController : ApiController
{
    IMovieRepository repo;

    public MovieController(IMovieRepository _repo)
    {
        this.repo = _repo;
    }

    [Route("latest")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            //var getAllMovies = repo.GetAll();
            return Ok("hello");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

You could hit something like "Parameterless constructor not found". 
That would be because your dependency injection is not well configured (no implementation of IMovieRepository is found in your dependency container)